# Managing Multiple Database Connections

Tags: java, database, ejb, eclipselink, entitymanager

I've been struggling with this problem for days,

Here is the scenario: 
I have several databases, one for each of my customers, all of them with the same 
structure(same tables and columns), so my application needs to decide at runtime with which one it needs to connect. I'm using JPA2, EclipseLink and EJB3.

My first attempt was to implement a custom EntityManager with all the logic to performs the operations on the right database, then I configured this EntityManager as an Stateless EBJ in order to make it possible to inject it with the @EBJ annotation (as described at this link: http://www.hostettler.net/blog/2012/11/20/multi-tenancy/). I coundn't make it work because it was throwing an exception when trying to inject the EntityManager.

So I decided to try something else, I've created EntityManagerFactory and I passed the 
JTA_DATASOURCE to it(after decide at runtime which one to use), so it could connect to the 
right database.

Here is the code:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class TestEntDAO {

    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        em = getEntityManager();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        Map props = new HashMap();
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.TRANSACTION_TYPE, "JTA");
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, dataSourceName());
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testePU", props);
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }

    public String dataSourceName(){
        if(someCondition){
            return "db1";
        }else{
            return "db2";
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly, the only problem is that the transaction is not managed by the 
container, so I had to explicitly mark the transaction's boundaries(call begin() and 
commit()). I could just use the @PersistenceContext annotation to make it work, but then I 
wouldn't have the EntityManagerFactory to pass the datasource.

Does anyone know of a way to use the Container-Managed Transactions(CMT) and still be able 
to pass the datasource?

Comment: Why can't you inject the datasource name? Or read it from a properties file?

Comment: I just couldn't find a way to do it and use the @PersistenceContext at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to define 3 Data sources and 3 Persistence units.

```
<persistence-unit name="PU1">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/DS1</jta-data-source>
  ...
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="PU2">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/DS2</jta-data-source>
  ...
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="PU3">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/DS3</jta-data-source>
  ...
</persistence-unit>
```

And inject Entity manager from whatever Persistence unit you want.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU2")
EntityManager em;
```

This should work, although I didn't test it.

Comment: I've already tried this, it worked, but if one of the connections fails the application won't deploy.

Comment: Maybe it can be overcome. What kind of error did you have?

Comment: Something like this --> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The connection attempt failed.

Comment: Consider asking a new question with the full stack trace as well as you info about app server and DB with Datasource config.

Comment: Here is the new quetion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935889/application-does-not-deploy-when-the-database-is-not-available